# Using .Find as a range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I want to search along a row to find a string cell entry "Category 1" and insert a certain number of columns (based on another cell value) from this point. The new columns should then have labels "Category 2", "Category 3", etc.

So far I have managed to code it up to be able to do the above based on specific column indexes (not string cell entries). However, I have been trying to modify it so that I can use "Category 1" as a reference point for column insertion. My below code is my attempt at this but comes up with "Object doesn't support this property or method". When looking on microsoft's advice page on the .Find function it has very similar code to what I have used so I am really stumped on what is going wrong.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

```
Sub Add_Column()

    Dim aCount As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim bCol As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Range

    aCount = Range("B12").Value
    bCol = Cells(15, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With Worksheets(3)
        Set c = .Find("Category 1", LookIn:=xlValues)

        For a = 1 To aCount - 1
            For b = 1 To bCol
                c.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                Range("G15").Value = "Category" + Str(aCount - a + 1)
            Next b
        Next a
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: which line shows the error?

Answer (score 0):

A *Worksheet* has no `Find`-method, a *Range* has.
So the command should look like this:

```
Set c = .Cells.Find("Category 1", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

(`Cells` is a Range containing *all* cells of a worksheet)

I don't understand all the details of your code logic, but I assume that `Range("B12")` and `Range("G15")` are on `Worksheets(3)`? You should qualify all Ranges (tell Excel which worksheet you are referring to (else the ActiveSheet is used and that is not always what you want). And use `&` for string concatenation, not `+`

```
With Worksheets(3)
    aCount = .Range("B12").Value
    bCol = .Cells(15, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set c = .Cells.Find("Category 1", LookIn:=xlValues)

    For a = 1 To aCount - 1
        For b = 1 To bCol
            c.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Range("G15").Value = "Category" & Str(aCount - a + 1)
        Next b
    Next a
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Thomas! After amending my code with your suggestions, there are no errors. Unfortunately, the code isn't actually doing anything now when I input the amount of columns I want into B12 and run the macro - any suggestions?

Comment: As I said, I don't understand the logic of your code. Use the debugger and step thru the code, check values for `aCount` and `bCol` and what exactly the code does (and where it differs from what you expect).

Comment: So you input a value into b12 which aCount picks up. Then we want to cycle through each number in that value (from 1 to aCount) and create a new column for each. To do this I used c = .Find to find "Category 1" and offset the columns from there to insert a new column. i.e. I have found category 1 with the c object and then offset from this reference point in the for loop. The G15 is just a cell reference to label the new column. I guess the b parts to the code aren't actually needed but even when I remove these the code still comes up with nothing.

Comment: Should I be using c.Address for the range to offset from?

Comment: Try it now, there was a typo as the `.Cells` was missed off. I doubt it will work though as you are referencing G15 throughout. Actually the `b` loop looks redundant?

Comment: @SJR I added the .Cells and removed all b parts and still got no luck, unsure as to what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works.

```
Sub x()

Dim aCount, bCol As Long, c As Range, a As Long

With Worksheets(3)
    aCount = .Range("B12").Value
    If Not IsNumeric(aCount) Then Exit Sub
    
    bCol = .Cells(15, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set c = .Cells.Find("Category 1", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    For a = 1 To aCount - 1
        c.Offset(0, a).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        c.Offset(0, a).Value = "Category " & a + 1
    Next a
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I've just used this and nothing happened. However, when I took out the with Worksheets(3) and the End With, the code worked, but just for the row which "Category 1" is on, not for the whole column

Comment: You are probably referencing the wrong sheet then. It's usually safer to use names rather than indexes anyway.

Comment: Ah, I was messing around with different worksheet numbers before but putting the name makes more sense and works! I am now using 'y = c.Column' to obtain the column index but do you know how I can use that in the range for the offset function?

Comment: `c.Offset(0, a).entirecolumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight`